# Sidekiq Shutting down unexpectedly on staging server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

**Rails version - Rails 5.1.5**

**Ruby version - ruby 2.5.0p0**

**Sidekiq Version - 5.1.1**

Below is the log from sidekiq.log, it directly says "Shutting down" with no errors

> 2019-01-16T12:36:07.648Z 9671 TID-1d26lr ScrappingWebsiteWorker
>   JID-d6a67fd45f6a0aeaae4c00ec INFO: start 2019-01-16T12:36:09.174Z 9671
>   TID-1d26lr ScrappingWebsiteWorker JID-d6a67fd45f6a0aeaae4c00ec INFO:
>   done: 1.526 sec 2019-01-16T12:36:09.855Z 9671 TID-1d2br7
>   ScrappingWebsiteWorker JID-210d5cc7db6b22e463c338d3 INFO: start
>   2019-01-16T12:36:12.440Z 9671 TID-1fnqyf ScrappingWebsiteWorker
>   JID-e2e91163b608750cd5db5004 INFO: start 2019-01-16T12:36:12.789Z 9671
>   TID-1d2br7 ScrappingWebsiteWorker JID-210d5cc7db6b22e463c338d3 INFO:
>   done: 2.934 sec 2019-01-16T12:36:15.573Z 9671 TID-1fnqyf
>   ScrappingWebsiteWorker JID-e2e91163b608750cd5db5004 INFO: done: 3.133
>   sec 2019-01-16T19:35:01.947Z 9671 TID-brvk7 INFO: Shutting down

Logs when i start sidekiq again

> 2019-01-17T09:54:16.927Z 15968 TID-5z1nk INFO: Booting Sidekiq 5.1.1
>   with redis options {:url=>"redis://localhost:6379/0",
>   :id=>"Sidekiq-server-PID-15968"} 2019-01-17T09:54:16.933Z 15968
>   TID-5z1nk INFO: Cron Jobs - add job with name: schedule_test_job
>   2019-01-17T09:54:18.884Z 15968 TID-5z1nk INFO: Running in ruby 2.5.0p0
>   (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-linux] 2019-01-17T09:54:18.884Z
>   15968 TID-5z1nk INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing
>   details. 2019-01-17T09:54:18.884Z 15968 TID-5z1nk INFO: Upgrade to
>   Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org
>   2019-01-17T09:54:18.925Z 15968 TID-oryka2xto ScrappingWebsiteWorker
>   JID-264ed726f15e9d1c59db570c INFO: start

Below are the details of my server directory

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             2014648        0   2014648   0% /dev
tmpfs             404504    15720    388784   4% /run
/dev/xvda1      50758760 22119660  28622716  44% /
tmpfs            2022520       12   2022508   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            2022520        0   2022520   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs             404504        0    404504   0% /run/user/1000
```

Logs of /var/log/kern.log

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

How can i find out what is the issue for shutting down sidekiq ?

Comment: OS could be killing it due to memory issue

Comment: Can i check OS is killing it and what is solution for it ?

Comment: you can check the log in "/var/log/kern.log"

Comment: @Rohan Added logs for `/var/log/kern.log` in question. no errors received.